# Output sar command results to a csv file

Tags: shell, unix, sar

I'm relatively new to shell programming and would like to know if there is a simple way to output the results of the `sar` command to a `csv` file. Using `sar > file1.csv` does the job, but it is not properly formatted. All the data is present in one column. I tried this, but it was worse

```
sar -d -u -w 1 1 | grep -v Average | grep -v Linux | tr -s ' ' ',' | tr -d '\n' > file1.csv
```

Can anyone give me the right script to store the output of the `sar` command in a `csv` file. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sar -d -u -w 1 1 | grep -v Average | grep -v Linux |awk '{if ($0 ~ /[0-9]/) { print $1","$2","$4","$5","$6; }  }'



22:14:04,CPU,%nice,%system,%iowait
22:14:05,all,0.00,8.53,0.00
22:14:04,proc/s,,,
22:14:05,0.00,,,
22:14:04,DEV,rd_sec/s,wr_sec/s,avgrq-sz
22:14:05,dev8-0,0.00,0.00,0.00
```

outputs above enjoy

Comment: You could also set OFS="," in a BEGIN block.

Comment: Thanks. Can the same be extended to the top command?. I tried this but  I cant see the col names.       top -n1 -b |awk '{if ($0 ~ /[0-9]/) { print $1","$2","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14","$15; }  }' > file2000.csv

Comment: sure, its because it is capturing 0-9 so you could either strip that off which will list all of the top result   top -n1 -b |awk '{ print $1","$2","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14","$15;  }'     or ...  top -n1 -b |awk '{if (($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) || ($0 ~ /PID/ )) { print $1","$2","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14","$15; } }' 
  which will list PID line and all of the top result

Answer (score 56):

I know this is kind of old but you should, or could, use `sadf -dh -- <sar command>`. It is part of the [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_sadf.html) package and it will give you the csv output without any need for `awk` and regex. Actually, the latest versions are also able to output the info to JSON and XML. You can just pick your poison :)

Simple example:

```
$ sadf -dh -- -p
localhost.localdomain;-1;2014-06-13 08:47:02 UTC;LINUX-RESTART
# hostname;interval;timestamp;CPU;%user;%nice;%system;%iowait;%steal;%idle[...]
localhost.localdomain;600;2014-06-13 09:00:01 UTC;-1;8.80;0.01;1.65;9.51;0.00;80.03
localhost.localdomain;600;2014-06-13 09:10:01 UTC;-1;3.03;0.71;2.41;0.81;0.00;93.05
```

Comment: If it is a multi cpu-core system omitting h option in sadf will print one line per each cpu-core. This file will be easier to process.

Comment: This answer is heavily underrated.

Comment: **This answer should be marked as the solution**. It do not only gives an answer following the how the question was framed (pipe grep, awk, etc. for a long and complicated one-liner), but it advises the right tool for the job keeping the final solution simpler and more powerful!